# How to get rows where a field contains ( ) , [ ] % or +. using rlike SparkSQL function

Tags: regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say you have a Spark dataframe with multiple columns and you want to return the rows where the columns contains specific characters. Specifically you want to return the rows where at least one of the fields contains ( ) , [ ] % or +.
What is the proper syntax in case you want to use Spark SQL rlike function?

```
import spark.implicits._

val dummyDf = Seq(("John[", "Ha", "Smith?"),
                 ("Julie", "Hu", "Burol"),
                  ("Ka%rl", "G", "Hu!"),
                  ("(Harold)", "Ju", "Di+")
                 ).toDF("FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName")
dummyDf.show()

+---------+----------+--------+
|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName|
+---------+----------+--------+
|    John[|        Ha|  Smith?|
|    Julie|        Hu|   Burol|
|    Ka%rl|         G|     Hu!|
| (Harold)|        Ju|     Di+|
+---------+----------+--------+

Expected Output

+---------+----------+--------+
|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName|
+---------+----------+--------+
|    John[|        Ha|  Smith?|
|    Ka%rl|         G|     Hu!|
| (Harold)|        Ju|     Di+|
+---------+----------+--------+
```

My few attempts returns errors or not what expected even when I try to do it just for searching (.

I know that I could use the simple like construct multiple times, but I am trying to figure out to do it in a more concise way with regex and Spark SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using `rlike` method:

```
dummyDf.show()

+---------+----------+--------+
|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName|
+---------+----------+--------+
|    John[|        Ha|  Smith?|
|    Julie|        Hu|   Burol|
|    Ka%rl|         G|     Hu!|
| (Harold)|        Ju|     Di+|
|     +Tim|      Dgfg|   Ergf+|
+---------+----------+--------+

val df = dummyDf.withColumn("hasSpecial",lit(false))

val result = df.dtypes
              .collect{ case (dn, dt) => dn }
              .foldLeft(df)((accDF, c) => accDF.withColumn("hasSpecial", col(c).rlike(".*[\\(\\)\\[\\]%+]+.*") || col("hasSpecial")))

result.filter(col("hasSpecial")).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------+--------+----------+
|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName|hasSpecial|
+---------+----------+--------+----------+
|John[    |Ha        |Smith?  |true      |
|Ka%rl    |G         |Hu!     |true      |
|(Harold) |Ju        |Di+     |true      |
|+Tim     |Dgfg      |Ergf+   |true      |
+---------+----------+--------+----------+
```

You can also drop the `hasSpecial column` if you want.

Comment: It works (:. I just had to include `import org.spark.sql.functions.{col, expr}`. If anybody wants to use the regex in a sql string, additional \ are needed. For example `dummyDf.where("FirstName like '.*[\\\\(\\\\)\\\\[\\\\]%+]+.*' ")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.*[()\[\]%\+,.]+.*`

.* all character zero or more times

[()[]%+,.]+ all characters inside bracket  1 or more times

.* all character zero or more times